# Multiple ports for the SAME rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I'm trying to figure out a means of deploying my RAILS app (rails 3.2, apache, passenger). The app has two distinct means of communication.

1. Users connect to our https site as is usual for a rails app. This is signed by a standard commercial CA.
2. Automated machines connect to our site and use client certificate authentication and retrieve data. This is all managed by our own CA and certificates.

At the moment i am not considering balancing, the app will run on one machine.
I cannot combine the two methods using optional certificate checking on 443 as this would impact other apps running on the same apache instance so I believe i require two seperate ports for the app.

How should i go about managing this? Can apache be configured to point to the same application through seperate vhosts (possibly via proxying to passenger standalone)? Should i be looking to break my application into two seperate applications with some shared library or engine? Should i just deploy twice pointing to the same DB (how would this affect caching)?

Is there a better way to distinguish between connection ports than checking for the client cert and if so assume an automated connection?

I'm also interested in both hacks to get it to work quickly as well as the correct rails way to architect something like this.

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just use different domains and then separate them using vhosts?

Comment: Different domains is pretty much the same as using the same domain on different ports with separate vhosts. The problem is not how to setup the ports it's how to setup passenger and rails to make use of the different ports for the same underlying application.

Comment: Hum, interesting, since passenger works with an app by vhost, i'm not sure if this is possible or not. Can you move to a different web server setup like passenger -> unicorn (or even nginx -> unicorn)?

Comment: Not really. Particularly for browsing purposes we need to integrate into a apache instance running many other things out of our control. Possibly we could reverse proxy a apache port to a different server but i don't think the administrators would be pleased. ie No for the purpose of the question.

Answer (score 0):

In your rails app, if you're looking to have behaviour conditional on the request type, you can add a little helper method like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def api_request?
    request.port == 443
  end
end
```

Then in your other controllers:

```
class UserController < ApplicationController 
  def index
    @users = User.all
    if api_request?
      render :json => @users.to_json
    else
      render :action => :index
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Great, i assumed there would be access to the port somewhere in the request. Not marking as accepted though as i'm still looking for someone to answer the bigger setup issues.